# What is the meaning of this notation in permutations?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have 6 numbers:
$$ 1 | 1|  1|  2|  2|  3$$

I've put dividers to help see better.

The number of permutations that this can take is:

My book says that this is denoted by:

$$P(6;3,2,1)$$

What does this notation mean?

---

Aside from the notation, if I were to find the answer to the number of permutations, I would first choose three 1's, then the two 2's, and finally the one 3.

$$\binom{6}{3}*\binom{3}{2}*\binom{1}{1} = 60$$

---

Is that what the notation means?

Comment: What is your book? What is the context?

Comment: The notation means number of permutations of 6 things, three of one kind, two of another kind, 1 of a third kind.

Comment: Yes, computationally speaking you can take this as the definition. Gerry's comment is probably closer to the "definition" in the proper sense. But, as Jack notes, all notation is context-dependent and so it ultimately depends on how your book defines/talks about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [permutation of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets), often denoted as $\binom{6}{3,2,1}$ and defined here as 
$$\binom{6}{3,2,1} = \frac{6!}{3!2!1!}$$

which as you have found can be expressed as a series of selections:
$$\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}= \frac{6!}{3!3!}\frac{3!}{2!1!}\frac{1!}{1!0!} =  \frac{6!}{3!2!1!}$$
by cancellation (and $0!=1$).

Comment: So it is the same notation as the one I have shown?

Comment: Yours is a kind of in-line version, using the P for permutation, then the two layers separated by a semicolon. I'm fairly sure that you can drop the  ",1"s from the end also, but obviously that might be confusing in the form I've used here if there is only one multi-element. Maybe you would "ellipsis" them, $\binom{9}{3,1,\ldots}$ :-)